# My code suddenly stops writing at beyond 15500 iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm studying how to code in Python and I'm trying to recreate a code I did in college.

The code is based on a 2D Ising model applied to epidemiology. What it does is:

- it constructs a 2D 100x100 array using numpy, and assigns a value of -1 to each element.
- The energy is calculated based on the function `calc_h` in the script below.
- Then, the code randomly selects a cell from the lattice, changes the value to 1, then calculates the energy of the system again.
- Then, the code compares if the energy of the system is less than or equal to the previous configuration. If it does, it "accepts" the change. If it isn't, a probability is compared to a random number to determine if the change is "accepted". This part is done in the `metropolis` function.
- The code repeats the process using a while loop until the maximum specified iteration, `max_iterations`.
  -The code tallies the number of elements with a -1 value (which is the `s` variable) and the number of elements with a 1 value (which is the `i` variable) in the `countSI` function. The script appends to a text file every 500 iteratons.

**THE PROBLEM**

I ran the script and besides taking too long to execute, the tallying stops at 15500. The code doesn't throw any error, but it just keeps going. I waited for around 3 hours for it to finish but it still goes only up to 15500 iterations.

I've tried commenting out the writing to csv block and instead printing the values first to observe it as it happens, and there I see, it stops at 15500 again.

I have no idea what's wrong as it doesn't throw in any error, and the code doesn't stop.

Here's the whole script. I put a description of what the part does below each block:

```
import numpy as np
import random as r
import math as m
import csv

init_size = input("Input array size: ")
size = int(init_size)
```

> this part initializes the size of the 2D array. For observation purposes, I selected a 100 by 100 latice.

```
def check_overflow(indx, size):
    if indx == size - 1:
        return -indx
    else:
        return 1
```

> I use this function for the `calc_h` function, to initialize a circular boundary condition. Simply put, the edges of the lattice are connected to one another.

```
def calc_h(pop, J1, size):
    h_sum = 0
    r = 0
    c = 0

    while r < size:
        buffr = check_overflow(r, size)
        while c < size:
            buffc = check_overflow(c, size)
            h_sum = h_sum + J1*pop[r,c] * pop[r,c-1] * pop[r-1,c] * pop[r+buffr,c] * pop[r,c+buffc]
            c = c + 1
        c = 0
        r = r + 1

    return h_sum
```

> this function calculates the energy of the system by taking the sum of the product of the value of a cell, its top, bottom, left and right neighbors, multiplied to a constant `J`.

```
def metropolis(h, h0, T_):
    if h <= h0:
        return 1
    else:
        rand_h = r.random()
        p = m.exp(-(h - h0)/T_)
        if rand_h <= p:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

> This determines whether the change from -1 to 1 is accepted depending on what `calc_h` gets.

```
def countSI(pop, sz, iter):
    s = np.count_nonzero(pop == -1)
    i = np.count_nonzero(pop == 1)
    row = [iter, s, i]
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as si_csv:
        tally_data = csv.writer(si_csv)
        tally_data.writerow(row)
        si_csv.seek(0)
```

> This part tallies the number of -1's and 1's in the lattice.

```
def main():
    J = 1 
    T = 4.0 
    max_iterations = 150000

    population = np.full((size, size), -1, np.int8) #initialize population array
```

> The 2D array is initialized in `population`.

```
    h_0 = calc_h(population, J, size)

    turn = 1
    while turn <= max_iterations:
        inf_x = r.randint(1,size) - 1
        inf_y = r.randint(1,size) - 1

        while population[inf_x,inf_y] == 1:
            inf_x = r.randint(1,size) - 1
            inf_y = r.randint(1,size) - 1

        population[inf_x, inf_y] = 1
        h = calc_h(population, J, size)

        accept_i = metropolis(h,h_0,T)
```

> This is the main loop, where a random cell is selected, and whether the change is accepted or not is determined by the function `metropolis`.

```
        if (accept_i == 0):
            population[inf_x, inf_y] = -1

        if turn%500 == 0 :
            countSI(population, size, turn)
```

> The script tallies every 500th iteration.

```
        turn = turn + 1
        h_0 = h

main()
```

The expected output is a text file with the tallies of the number of the `s` and `i` every 500th iteration. something that looks like this:

```
500,9736,264
1000,9472,528
1500,9197,803
2000,8913,1087
2500,8611,1389
3000,8292,1708
3500,7968,2032
4000,7643,2357
4500,7312,2688
5000,6960,3040
5500,6613,3387
6000,6257,3743
6500,5913,4087
7000,5570,4430
7500,5212,4788
```

I have no idea where to start at a solution. At first, I thought it was the writing to csv that's causing the problem, but probing through the print function proves otherwise. I tried to make it as concise as I can.

I hope you guys can help! I really wanna learn this language and start simulating a lot of stuff, and I think this mini project is a great starting step for me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd replace `turn != max_iterations + 1` with `turn <= max_iterations`.

Comment: could you include doc strings or an explanation of what the code is doing / what algorithm you're using?

Comment: @Dan, sure I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew, the script constructs a 100 by 100 array of with default values of -1. A random cell is selected and changed to 1, depending on the calculation of energy. This random selection is repeated for m number of times, where m is the number of iterations.

Comment: The file would contain something like: 500, 9987, 23
1000, 9664, 336
1500, 9421, 579
2000, 9011, 89
...

Comment: Thanks for answering follow-up questions to your question, but please instead [edit] your question to add any relevant information. Any question on Stack Overflow should make sense on its own so that other users finding this question in the future won't have to dig through all the comments to understand your post. Search engines will do a better job of finding your post if everything is at the right place. Also by explanation I meant each function e.g `calc_h`. At the moment this is just a wall of code.

Comment: Okay sorry. Thank you. I'm gonna try to rephrase it and make it as concise as possible.

Comment: What’s the last line printed? Could it be possible your code stucks in the second while loop (where you’re looking for next value to flip)?

Comment: The last line is whatever the values are at 15500 iterations. For instance, 15500,71,9929.

Comment: Maybe I can only iterate up to a certain value?

Comment: Your code is probably wrong. It will block in that nested while loop whenever the number of spins to flip is smaller than the number of iterations. In your example from the previous comment, the size of the population is 10000 and you want to flip 15500 spins. Note that once spin is flipped up (with 100% prob), it will be flipped down with smaller prob, due to metropolis sampling.

Comment: Oh. okay I get it. So essentially, at beyond 15500 iterations, most likely I have taken into account every single cell in the poplulation and therefore, since the while loop doesn't stop until it reaches the maximum iterations, it gets stuck. Wow I totally overlooked that one. I relied too much on my memory where I explicitly remember having around 150000 iterations on my old code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the spread is going too fast, I'm gonna figure out how to fix that. Also, I think adding some kind of switch when all the cells are flipped would solve the problem, right?

Comment: It would probably solve the problem at hand, but I’m not sure that’s the general solution you want. Depends on what exactly you’re trying to do.

Comment: Do you have suggestions based on what I presented here?

Comment: The problem is acually in the algorithm you’re implementing here. Are you trying to implement simulated annealing, or something else? Right now, as you approach the size of your population with number of iterations, you will see more and more slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by [@randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311442/my-code-suddenly-stops-writing-at-beyond-15500-iterations/56321235#comment99248316_56311442):

> Your code is probably wrong. It will block in that nested while loop whenever the number of spins to flip is smaller than the number of iterations. In your example from the previous comment, the size of the population is 10000 and you want to flip 15500 spins. Note that once spin is flipped up (with 100% prob), it will be flipped down with smaller prob, due to metropolis sampling.

works.